# What would be the row counts for Inner, Left, Right and Full Joins

Tags: oracle

```
Col1                    Col2   
1                         2    
2                         1    
3                         1    
3                         2    
3                         2    
4                         4    
4                         6    
5                         7           
6                         8    
6                         8    
7                         9
```

What would be the row counts for Inner, Left, Right and Full Joins?

i need the output number of rows. I have the duplicate values and need the answer for this question.

What would be the row counts for Inner, Left, Right and Full Joins?

Answer (score 1):

Total number of elements in both: 11

Distinct values in the first: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Distinct values in the second: 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9

- **Inner**: 10
- **Left**: 14
- **Right**: 13
- **Full**: 121

```
create table t1(num int);

insert into t1(num)
values (1),(2),(3),(3),(3),(4),(4),(5),(6),(6),(7);

create table t2(num int);

insert into t2(num)
values (2),(1),(1),(2),(2),(4),(6),(7),(8),(8),(9);
```

and

```
select count(*)
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.num = t2.num;

select count(*)
from t1
left join t2
on t1.num = t2.num;

select count(*)
from t1
right join t2
on t1.num = t2.num;

select count(*)
from t1
full join t2;
```

## Explanation

In order to compute these "by hand", you can have this rule of thumb:

- inner join: the sum of Xi * Yi, where i is a common matching element and Xi being the number of its occurrence in the first table, Yi being the number of its occurrence in the second table
- left join: the sum of Xi * Yi (see inner join) + sum of Xj, where j is an element that is present at the first table, but not at the second table
- right join: the sum of Xi * Yi (see inner join) + sum of Yk, where k is an elemenebt that is present at the second table, but not at the first table
- full join: the product of the number of records at both tables, in this case 11 * 11 = 121